# Having clarification in pointer and array in c

Tags: c

I want to know what is the value available in *p=c,*q=c, because c is declared has an array what is the value available in ++q and also in second forloop in ++p.I have tested in turbo c it gives the output,2 2 2 2 2 2 3 4 6 5 here I am unable to follow the process.I request the stack team to  give the explanation.
.

```
main()
{
    int c[]={2.8,3.4,4,6.7,5};
    int j,*p=c,*q=c;
    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        printf(" %d ",*c);
        ++q;     
    }
    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        printf(" %d ",*p);
        ++p;     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`q` is a pointer and you need to dereference the pointer to get the value

```
printf(" %d ",*c);
```

should be

```
printf(" %d ",*q);
```

In the first loop `c` is an array name and there is a concept of array decaying to a pointer which you dereference and get the value stored in the array but `c` is unmodified in the first loop so you get the same value always whereas in the second loop you are moving your pointer by doing `p++`

Comment: Thanks I understood. here is c is unmodified what is the value of ++q in first loop and  ++p in second loop, it has address or c[0] like that. because in second loop it increase the ++p. I want to know what is happening in ++p. and what value of ++p in initial level

Answer (score 0):

```
printf(" %d ",*c);
               ^ c is an integer array not pointer .
```

Correct would be

```
printf(" %d ",*q);
```

`q` is pointer and should be dereferenced to get value it points to .

### EDIT

```
int j,*p=c,*q=c;
```

So here it is similar to

```
int j,*p,*q=c;
p=c;
```

So the `p` points to address of initial element of array `c` that is address of `c[0]`.

And it is incrementated

```
   `++p`  // Pointer moves to the next int position (as if it was an array)
    //in this case increments to c[1] ,c[2] till c[n-1] in every iteration
```

Note- If you want to increment the value of pointer you can do this `++*p`.

Comment: Thanks I understood. here is c is unmodified what is the value of ++q in first loop and ++p in second loop, it has address or c[0] like that. because in second loop it increase the ++p. I want to know what is happening in ++p. and what value of ++p in initial level

Answer (score 0):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

```
int c[]={2.8,3.4,4,6.7,5};
```

You've declared `c` as an array of `int`, and the size is taken from the number of elements in the initializer (5).  Note that the floating-point values in the initializer (2.8, 3.4, 6.7) will have their fractional portion discarded (2, 3, 6).  If you want an array of floating-point values, you must declare it as either `float` or `double` instead of `int`.

In the declaration

```
int j,*p=c,*q=c;
```

`c` is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, so it is converted to a pointer expression, and its value is the address of the first element in the array, so both `p` and `q` are initialized with the *address* of the first element in `c`.  In memory, it would look something like this (addresses are pulled out of thin air, and we're going to assume 4-byte `int`s, 4-byte pointers, and a big-endian architecture):

```
Item        Address            0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
----        -------            ----  ----  ----  ----
   c        0x80001000         0x00  0x00  0x00  0x02
            0x80001004         0x00  0x00  0x00  0x03
            0x80001008         0x00  0x00  0x00  0x04
            0x8000100c         0x00  0x00  0x00  0x06
            0x80001010         0x00  0x00  0x00  0x05
   j        0x80001014         0x??  0x??  0x??  0x?? // ?? represents unknown byte value
   p        0x80001018         0x80  0x00  0x10  0x00
   q        0x8000101c         0x80  0x00  0x10  0x00
```

Both `p` and `q` contain the address of the first element of `c`.  `j` is not explicitly initialized, so its value is indeterminate.

In your first loop,

```
for(j=0;j<5;j++)
{
    printf(" %d ",*c);
    ++q;     
}
```

You're *dereferencing* `c` (which is allowed; since `c` is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it's converted to a pointer type); `*c` is equivalent to `c[0]`, and it evaluates to the value of the first element of `c`, which is `2`.  You then update the value of `q` to point to the next element of `c`, but you don't do anything with it.  Changing the value in `q` does not affect the value in `c`.

In the second loop,

```
for(j=0;j<5;j++)
{
    printf(" %d ",*p);
    ++p;     
}
```

You're printing the value that `p` *points to*.  Initially `p` points to the first element of `c`; each time through the loop, `p` is updated to point to the next element of `c`, sort of like this:

```
j    p              *p                
-    ----------     --
0    0x80001000      2
1    0x80001004      3
2    0x80001008      4
3    0x8000100c      6
4    0x80001010      5
```

The same thing is happening with `q` in the first loop, you just aren't using it in the print statement.

Note that `p++` doesn't simply add 1 to the value stored in `p`; pointer arithmetic takes the size of the pointed-to type into account, so that `p++` will advance `p` to point to the next element of that type.  If the type of `*p` is `char` (size 1), then it will advance 1 byte.  If the type of `*p` is a four-byte integer, then it will advance 4 bytes.

Note that even though the *expression* `c` may be converted to a pointer type under most circumstances, the *object* that `c` designates is not a pointer.  `c` does not *store* an address anywhere.  Also, `c` may not be the operand of the `++` or `--` operators, nor may it be the target of an assignment; you can change the values stored in each `c[i]`, but you cannot change the value of `c` itself.

Answer (score 0):

have a look on your code

first of all your

1.you are declaring the array and initialising it with some values.

`int *p=c`;

int *p
and p=c; //name of array store address of first element.

so here p is an pointer type variable which store starting address of an array.Now in your first loop you doing

```
 printf(" %d ",*c);// c contain address ,*c contain the value of that address(means value of zeroth address of array).
```

and your incrementing 'q' which has no effect on c;

it print '2' not '2.8' because of it integer nature.

now in second loop

```
printf(" %d ",*p); // it prints first element of array in first iteration
```

then you incrementing value  of p;
  now see

what ++p do?

first p point to zeroth address of array now p is an int type so when  you incrementing it now it jumps to 4 byte(let suppose int size) ahead and in that address your next element of array i.e 3 is store.